# Polymer- use behavior to share object between elements?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Is it possible to use behaviors to share a object between elements?

```
<script>
  selectedBehavior = {
    properties: {
      selected: Object
    }
  }
</script>
```

---

```
<dom-module id="paper-menu-custom">
  <style>
  </style>
  <template>
    <paper-menu attr-for-selected="name" selected="{{selected.choice}}">
    ...
  <script>
    Polymer({
        is: "paper-menu-custom",
        behaviors: [selectedBehavior]
    });
```

---

```
  toolbars = document.querySelector('paper-menu-custom');
  toolbars.selected.choice = "home";
```

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'choice' of undefined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to use a behavior to share information between elements.

You should use [IronMeta](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-meta) like so :

- Declaratively and with data-binding :

`<iron-meta key="my-unique-key" value="{{mySharedInformation}}"></iron-meta>`

Then use `mySharedInformation` the same way you would any custom element's `properties`. Setting it will update the value of any other `<iron-meta>` in your code that shares the same key.

- In plain javascript :

Read

`var mySharedInformation = new Polymer.IronMeta().byKey('my-unique-key');`

Write

`new Polymer.IronMeta({key: 'my-unique-key', value: mySharedInformation});`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at my  object in github (https://github.com/akc42/akc-meta), it allows one element to publish a value with a key, and other ti have multiple instances subscribe to it and get the data out again.

It does it by keeping instances in a private variable

```
(function(){
var private;

Polymer({element definition has access to private});


})();
```

Comment: The documentation with <iron-meta> was ambiguous, so I did a few experiments and it didn't seem to work the way I was expecting (I can't quite remember the issue, I think it was to do with changing the value and having it propagate to all the query elements). I tried looking at the code and it appeared very complicated, and I thought (originally) that akc-meta would be a lot simpler.  In the end it still was simpler, but less so after I found I had to handle elements detaching from the DOM.  My motivation was just a proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

I got it with this:

```
<script>
  selectedBehavior = {
    properties: {
      selected: { 
        type: Object,
        value: function() { return { choice: 'home'} }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

It seems specifying a object is not enough. I need to return a object for the value of object. Doesn't make alot of sense because in documentation I should just be able to say `foo: Object`. But, maybe this is a special case sense I am using it as a behavior.

**Unfortunately**, two elements can not share the same obj.property through behaviors. Each will have it's own instance.

Comment: upvoting for the last sentence - learned it the hard way just now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share an object between the different instances of your element, you have to avoid using a function as describe in the [Documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#configure-values)
So this should be working as you expect:

```
<script>
  selectedBehavior = {
    properties: {
      selected: { 
        type: Object,
        value: { choice: 'home'} }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked also, however it didn't accomplish what I was aiming for....two elements to share `selected.choice`. When `home` is changed to something else, the change is not reflected in the other element.

Comment: be sure to use `this.set(...)` API to modify an object!

Comment: yep....I used the `set` api to make sure to update the elements. I guess it has to do with local dom and isolation.